# Getting Preferences in TableLayout Class

Tags: android

I have a class that extends TableLayout to set up my tableview however on that page itself, I want to get my SharedPreferences however there is no such supported method getSharedPreferences() in TableLayout other than Activity. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

`getSharedPreferences` doesn't belong to `Activity`, but to `Context`, and every widget in Android needs a reference to a Context. So, if you extend TableLayout you are passing to your new class a Context in the constructor, aren't you? You could access getSharedPreferenreces from there, couldn't you?

On the other hand, accessing `getSharedPreferences` from a custom widget looks like a really terrible design. Don't do that. Pass wathever info you need from shared preferences to your widget through its constructor.